# i need custom_field value in order_invoice.tpl (opencart)

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add the value from a custom field it calls BTW number in order_invoice.tpl.
BTW nummer(VAT number) is in the frontend by account register. 
there is $order array in order_invoice.tpl but it doesn't include BTW number. 
how can i get a custom field value in order_invoice.tpl ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you copy and paste the code you are talking about please.

Comment: this cannot be easy done. You have to edit few controllers, modules and templates. There's a vqmod for Company ID / VAT ID which creates two fields in db and generates in user profile, email invoices etc.